# Use Instance of Object called via CLI in Web-environment

Tags: php, multithreading, command-line-interface

I'm developing a scheduler class which is used to fetch data from some connected devices in defined cycles. Since I'm starting the scheduler via PHP CLI (the scheduler is designed for infinite runtime), i'd like to make the Scheduler Class manageable, for instance I want to check status and stop the current scheduler.
The routine looks like this: `while($this->run){
do some fancy fetching stuff here}`

I'd like to change the var run for this very instace of the scheduler class, so is it possible to store that instance maybe in a file or something like this, so i could pass it to an manager class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some ideas:

- simple with **files**: when you start the scheduler it generates a **unique id (GUID/UUID)**, e.g. using [**uniqid**](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.uniqid.php), and displays it, say "123456a1b2c3", on stdout so that external processes can identify it.
  Then the scheduler writes in a file named, "123456a1b2c3.out", all the monitoring info: heart beat, number of tasks... and read from another file, "123456a1b2c3.in", some instructions: "stop", "restart"...
- more involved but more powerful with a **database**: instead of using the file-system use a database like **MySQL** if you already have one and need to manage the schedulers in a **distributed fashion**, or **SQLite** if there is only one machine (though you could also use it with a distributed FS) and you don't want a full fledged DB for such a basic requirement.

Comment: thanks for your ideas. I tried to get it done with a static class but Now i'm goin to use your database way.